# Can a Controller be Invoked from a normal Java Class

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Wanted to know if it is possible to invoke a controller and return a view from a normal Java File.

**For Example:**

```
@Controller
class ToBeInvokedController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/invoke")
    public String invokedMethod() {
        return "view_name";
    }
}


class DemoJava{
    //Want to Invoke the method InvokedMethod() of ToBeInvokedController class and return the view_name
}
```

Comment: try it and see.

Comment: It's just like any other java method. You can obviously invoke it.

Comment: What is the purpose? Is it for testing the controller?

Comment: @Bnrdo No it's not for testing, I wanted to call the method in the controller so it returns a JSP

Comment: @Nikhil JSPs are being rendered by ViewResolver. You configure ViewResolver to view the JSP page on the browser. If you invoke through Java class, you can get page name. It is ViewResolver that works behind the scene. Refer https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html and http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/ViewResolver.html.

Answer (score 1):

Just Create an object of it and invoke it like normal method.

Like :

```
class DemoJava{
    ToBeInvokedController c = new ToBeInvokedController();
    String s = c.InvokedMethod();
    System.out.print(s)
}
```

Comment: But will it return to that view? Like how a normal controller works i.e a Jsp is returned when a method which is a RequestMapper it is called.!

Comment: It will return `String`. If you prepare `HTML` manually in `String` form in this method then yes it will return that form.

Answer (score 0):

> Wanted to know if it is possible to invoke a controller and return a
>   view from a normal Java File.

Yes, you can but you need to instantiate the `ToBeInvokedController` class Since it's a non-static method.

```
ToBeInvokedController obj = new ToBeInvokedController();
obj.InvokedMethod();
```

if it would have been a **static** method you can invoke it directly via

```
ToBeInvokedController.InvokedMethod();
```

I strong suggest you to use **camelCase** convention when naming methods in Java

Comment: Thanks but I want to return a Jsp when a controller is called like how a normal controller works , and this is just an example so would not worry about the camelCasing very much.

Comment: @Nikhil A controller never returns a JSP, it only returns a name which gets resolved via ViewResolver which you have defined in your configuration xml file. Normal controller works like this only.

Comment: Ya, my bad a typo, I meant I wanted to know will the invokedMethod() return a JSP ? in your above solution! And configuration for the particular JSP file to be returned is already in the tiles.xml.

Comment: Yes, Nikhil it will return **JSP fiile name**.

Comment: so you are saying it will render a view of the jsp file?